# Different table name for Paper Trail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Is it possible to specify a different table name (other than `versions`) for the [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem?

In my Rails app, I already have a Versions model/table, which has nothing to do with active record versioning (my app let's uses fork a "prototype" and for better or worse I used "version" as a label for these forks). It is quite pervasive through my app, and I don't want to rename this.

When running `bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install`, I get `Migration already exists: create_versions`.

Basically, I would like the table to be `PaperTrailVersions` along with the methods to access the trail to be similarly namespaced.

Any ideas? Or should I just use the [Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem which uses a `audits` table?

Comment: Is this helpful https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/128

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PaperTrail supports [custom version classes](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/a287d6e2e06dad526d71461df8e5b77c5ce324f3/README.md#6a-custom-version-classes) which can have custom table names defined.

```
class PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  self.table_name = :post_versions
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :class_name => 'PostVersion'
end
```

As of the failed `generate` command, I would try these steps (haven't tested them though):

- You already have a migration with the name `CreateVersions` because you already have a `versions` table. That is why the `generate` command fails - it cannot create a migration with the same name. I think that you can simply **temporarily rename the old migration** (for your original `versions` table migration). You just need to rename the file *and* the classname inside the file.
- Then the **`generate`** command should run. It should install a few files, their names will be printed out to the console.
- Now open the newly generated `create_versions` migration file and rename it as well as the class name inside from `CreateVersions` **to a name according to your custom versions table name**, such as `CreatePostVersions`. Also rename any mention of the `versions` table inside it to your custom table name, e.g. `post_versions`.
- Open **all other generated migrations** and change the `versions` table names to your custom table names inside them. There is no need to rename these files though.
- Now go back to your original (and now temporarily renamed) `create_versions` migration file and rename it back to its original name (**revert the changes** on this file).
- **Try to run the migrations!** It should work now.

The steps may seem cumbersome but they just temporarily rename the old migration to something else so that the generation command can run. Then you just need to change the table name inside the generated migration to the new table name.

The files that will be generated with the `generate` command can be seen [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/tree/master/lib/generators/paper_trail/templates) in the source code. These are the files that you'll need to modify.

Comment: This example shows a model-specific `PostVersion`, but it should also be possible for all models to use the same custom version class.